# What's the meaning of "Seasoned as old leather"?

Tags: meaning

I checked Longman Dictionary and there are three definition for "Seasoned":

> 1 [only before noun] used to describe someone who has a lot of experience of a particular thing
>
> 2 seasoned food has salt, pepper etc added to it
>
> 3 seasoned wood has been prepared for use by drying

However I do not understand  meaning of the phrase.

Could you please tell me what the meaning of "Seasoned as old leather" is?

The full text is here:

> When Grandpa-down-the-hill was a young man, there’d been herds of
>   livestock spread across the mountain, and they were tended on horseback.
>   Grandpa’s ranching horses were the stuff of legend. **Seasoned as old
>   leather**, they moved their burly bodies delicately, as if guided by the rider’s
>   thoughts.

Comment: Note that Cooking SE is named “Seasoned Advice”, playing with meaning 1 and 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Longmans meaning (1). Also [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/seasoned):

> having a lot of experience of doing something and therefore knowing
>   how to do it well:
>
> a seasoned traveller
>   a seasoned campaigner for human rights

The horses are seasoned, that is they are very experienced in their role, in this case carrying humans who are tending cattle. Also, a simile is being used - leather, e.g. that of a boot or jacket which has been worn and used over a long period, becomes 'seasoned' - soft and supple and well adapted to the wearer.

Comment: Anyone who has tried to break in a brand-new baseball glove will also understand this metaphor.